# Перенос информации из комментариев в ответ — удалять ли комментарии?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, тревоги

Имеется [ответ на вопрос "Несколько RewriteRule для одного набора условий RewriteCond"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/415840).

У меня с юзером было обсуждение, в результате я обновил ответ, чтобы там были разобраны все проблемы (а не только одна, которую я изначально заметил). Так как комментарии фактически устарели (всё нужное уже в ответе), то свои комментарии я удалил, а комментарии автора вопроса отметил как устаревшие.

Однако модератор не счёл комментарии устаревшими: у меня в профиле тревоги отмечены как отклонённые.

Почему?

Насколько я понимаю, такие комментарии следует удалять: [Removing comments that are no longer relevant, but were at the time of posting (MSO)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281473/removing-comments-that-are-no-longer-relevant-but-were-at-the-time-of-posting).

Или мои действия были слишком неочевидными, и следовало явно описать причину удаления, а не пользоваться стандартной причиной? Мои удалённые комментарии отображаются для ромбовых модераторов, когда они рассматривают мою тревогу?

Comment: Видны только удаленные вопросы, комментарии - нет. Причину, конечно, лучше явно указать. Когда смотришь десятка три тревог, не всегда понятно что и почему. Я иногда откатываю тревоги по комментариям, но этого вопроса не припомню.

Comment: Таки при помощи дополнительных телодвижений увидеть удаленные комментарии модератор может.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Да, удалять.**

1. Информация по вопросу должна быть в вопросе, а решение — в ответе.
2. Среди этих комментариев теряются другие, например с важными ссылками.
3. Ухудшается читаемость всей страницы в целом, если под вопросом и каждым ответом находится портянка из комментариев.

> **Инструкция для общего случая, когда в диалоге под вопросом или ответом уточняются детали решения.**

#### 1. Перенесите всю важную информацию из комментариев в вопрос и/или ответ

1. Комментарии от автора, раскрывающие дополнительные подробности вопроса, нужно перенести в вопрос.
2. Комментарии от отвечающего — перенести в ответ.

#### 2. Вместе с собеседником удалите комментарии

Лучше всего — удалить свои комментарии самостоятельно и предложить то же самое собеседнику. Это быстро и не требует вмешательства модератора.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### 3. Если это не помогло — используйте тревогу

Если собеседник не реагирует или больше не заходит на сайт — используйте тревогу на комментарии, пункт « устаревший».

Если таких комментариев очень много — лучше отметить тревогой весь вопрос или ответ, под которым находятся комментарии: «требуется вмешательство модератора», написать «информация перенесена в сообщение, комментарии устарели, желательно их удалить».

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### 4. Что не нужно удалять:

- Комментарии вне диалога, содержащие ссылки на сторонние ресурсы. Это как раз то место, где и должны быть эти ссылки.
- Комментарии, указывающие на близкие по теме вопросы. Они могут быть полезны будущим читателям.