# Пожалуйста, переносите всё важное из комментариев в вопрос и ответ

Tags: обсуждение, правки, комментарии

В последнее время часто встречаю долгие дискуссии под вопросами или ответами. В самих дискуссиях ничего плохого нет, они по теме и в рамках профессионального общения. Но есть одна проблема.

Предположим, что я не фанатик StackOverflow, а обычный разработчик. Ищу в поисковике ответ по интересующей меня проблеме и одна из ссылок уводит меня на SO на русском. Там я вижу отличный ответ от участника, у которого репутация — как моя зарплата в копейках. Наверное, ответ хороший. Но есть одна проблема: *под ним несколько десятков комментариев.*

- Что мне делать, нужно ли их читать?
- Но я же потеряю лишние 10 минут, чтобы вникнуть в суть обсуждения, а вдруг там ничего полезного?
- А вдруг в ответе ошибка, про которую в комментариях написали?
- Или там решение ещё получше?
- О, боже, да там ещё и код запостили! Это решение?
- А, нет, это они перешли на обсуждение концептуальных вопросов языка...

Всё-таки комментарии задуманы как временные сообщения, используемые в процессе поиска решения. Ими можно уточнять подробности задачи, можно указывать на недочёты в решении. Но для долговременного хранения информации они не подходят.

Поэтому, пожалуйста, после бурного обсуждения кристаллизуйте суть и смысл и переносите их:

- Уточнения подробностей вопроса — в текст вопроса.
- Уточнения подробностей ответа — в ответ!
- Возражения к ответу (когда автор ответа не согласен) можно переформулировать и опубликовать одним комментарием.
- А все [устаревшие комментарии, пожалуйста, удаляйте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/189/181472).

Будущие читатели будут вам благодарны.

Если вы хотите сохранить всю историю обсуждения — перенесите вопросы в чат. Если система не предлагает — всегда можно позвать [модераторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), благо их четверо и хоть кто-то обычно есть [в общем чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Comment: возможно, стоти упомянуть (если ещё не упомянут) [этот ответ](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1001/178576).

Comment: в тему: [Перевод раздела справки “Что такое комментарий?”](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2317/23044)

Comment: @jfs да, помню про это предложение.