# Почему в комментарии должно быть обязательно не меньше 15 символов?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии

Я знаю, сайт делается за бугром. Мне порой надо ответить просто "Да" или "Нет", когда меня спрашивают. Отправьте разработчикам, чтобы исправили эту проблему!

Comment: Да.............

Comment: Д̣̙̒ͫ̅а̯ͪ̔͊̈͗ͣ̈̄ͬ

Comment: Д‌‌​​‌‌‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌​​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌а

Comment: Процитируйте тот фрагмент, на который отвечаете "да". Делов-то...

Comment: ​​‌‌‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌​​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​

Comment: Д̴̪̜͗̽̈́̿ӑ̵̡̤͎̠̻̓̈́̏̆

Comment: @NewView пожалуйста поясните позицию, кто и для чего тут ваши комментарии парсит? (и как это относится к заданному вопросу)

Comment: Там же ссылка есть, и это вроде не секрет Полишинеля, для чего это и почему такие правила. MS самый крупный инвестор StackExchange, и все правила вопросов и ответов ими давно и четко продуманы. К вопросу относиться напрямую, Да/Нет не является информативным ответом, и представляет из себя мусор с точки зрения создания тикета проблемы..

Comment: @NewView по ссылке достаточно объемный текст и прочтя его по диагонали, ответа на вопрос там не обнаружил. Спасибо что уточнили точку зрения )

Comment: @NewView учитывая, что Documentation уже свёрнута давно, ссылка (и вся статья) теряет свою актуальность. Но вообще было интересно узнать, что есть такая дока у MS.

Comment: У них ещё любопытная страница была, трёх летней давности, о планах на будущее со StackOwerflow, но они вычистили её чуть больше чем полностью :) урл не существует, могу в архиве порыться если интересно, кажется сохранял.

Comment: @NewView комментарии и так считаются мусором по умолчанию; зачем для мусора вводить какие-то ещё дополнительные ограничения — непонятно

Comment: @NewView Спасибо, информация конечно интересная, но какого-то срыва покровов тут не наблюдается (наоборот, есть некоторая подтасовка - SO эволюционировал много лет и не был и не является продуктом MS), и к вопросу она непосредственно не относится. Интереснее как раз обоснование причины - чем 15 символов подрывают информативность ответов.

Comment: Это неведомо простому народу, @andreymal, вероятно тоже учитываются, мы же не в курсе про критерии отбора сообщений, можем только догадываться. Но думаю, возможно ошибаюсь что это нужно для отработки новой платформы после UWP, где программы будут писать уже сами программы :) с помощью каких либо визардов..

Comment: @Kromster, возможно 15 символов некая логическая еденица которая подразумевает наличие мысли в ответе :) а не логику - `сам дурак..` :)

Comment: Дело не в мысли. А вас спрашивают, допустим (прям пример из жизни) "Скажите, вам нужно разделить строку именно первым пробелом?" - При этом в описании проблемы я уже написал что нужно разделить строку первым пробелом. Ну и что бы не обижать спрашивающего пятидесятый раз - говорю, -Да. В любом случае, форма ответа бывает краткой, это не значит что там не содержится мысли. Скорее, дурак - тот кто думает, что краткая форма ответа не содержит мысли.

Comment: А как кратко поблагодарить, допустим, словом "Спасибо!".  - наверное писать "спасибо" три раза.

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko спасибы здесь прямо запрещены правилами так-то

Comment: @andreymal не согласен по поводу мусора, в комментариях порой содержится ценная информация

Comment: @Alex пихать в комментарии ценную информацию запрещено правилами Stack Overflow (и меня давно пора забанить за то, что я пихаю)

Comment: @andreymal а пруф на запрет есть (не видел ранее такую инфу) ?

Comment: @Alex, [Не благодарите автора ответа в комментариях - Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Grundy я про [другое](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8892/#comment36586_8892). Это [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8892/#comment36610_8892) не про спасибо и т.п.

Comment: @Alex, да, я потом только понял, что имелось в виду не то

Comment: @Alex вот [про комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) секция: Когда не следует оставлять комментарий?

Comment: @Alex, ну и например вопрос на мете: [Пожалуйста, переносите всё важное из комментариев в вопрос и ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2408/186999)

Comment: @gil9red это как?!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, третий коммент это текст с `Fingerprinting with Zero-Width Characters`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c092c81a4b547cd7cc10e2e4dcac8499bec1ac1b/Fingerprinting%20with%20Zero-Width%20Characters/main.py#L105

Comment: @andreymal, а у вас как так получилось?! :)

Comment: @gil9red удалил из коммента букву «Д» и букву «а», остальное отправил)

Comment: @andreymal, из моего комментария? :D

Answer (score 3):

На сайтах stackexchange много [странных ограничений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3392/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-stack-overflow). Считайте это местной фишкой.

Насчет длины комментария, скорее всего, смысл ограничения - предотвратить написание новичками бессмысленных комментариев типа "спасибо". Если хотите мое мнение, ограничение довольно бессмысленное, так как длина комментария и его полезность на самом деле имеют очень малую связь. К примеру, на GitHub в комментариях под issues нет ограничения на минимальную длину; вряд ли это ограничение нужно и здесь.

Так как решение разработчиков ввести минимальную длину комментария явно осознанное, бессмысленно сообщать им "чтобы исправили эту проблему"; вероятнее всего, они не считают это проблемой. Вместо этого, вы можете поставить плюс [предложению на meta stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments?noredirect=1&lq=1) и надеяться, что разработчики изменят свое мнение.